# Undo feature in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-2.x, text-widget

I was trying to use `undo` function on my text widget in `tkinter` but without any luck.
I tried it this way:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Notebook

def OnVsb(*args):
    text.yview(*args)
    numbers.yview(*args)

def OnMouseWheel(event):
    text.yview("scroll", event.delta,"units")
    numbers.yview("scroll",event.delta,"units")
    return "break"

def undo(*argv):
    text.edit_undo()

root = Tk()
defaultbg = root.cget('bg')
root.bind('<Control-z>', undo)
note = Notebook(root)
frame = Frame(note, bd=5, relief=GROOVE, padx=5, pady=5)
frame.pack()
bar = Scrollbar(frame, command=OnVsb)
bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
numbers = Listbox(frame, width=5, height=30,bg=defaultbg,relief=FLAT,   yscrollcommand=bar.set)
numbers.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
text = Text(frame,bd=3, width=145, height=30, yscrollcommand=bar.set)
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y) 
text.bind("<MouseWheel>", OnMouseWheel)
text.tag_config("attr", foreground="tomato")
text.tag_config("value", foreground="dark violet")
text.tag_config("tags", foreground="dodger blue")
text.tag_config("text", font=("Georgia", "9", "bold"))
text.focus_set()
root.lift()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
root.after_idle(root.call, 'wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', False)
root.mainloop()
```

But for some reason it does nothing. I thought it was implemented by default in text widget, but it didn't work out. Any suggestions on how to use this feature on a text widget? Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use arbitrary arguments, use a single reference to the event. That is, just one argument.

Comment: Please paste your whole code for more context.

Comment: Can you host a link to the full code somewhere to download it?

Comment: I don't see any change and I don't understand why you change share it.

Comment: Give me all the code where you initialize objects and define functions.

Comment: i updated the code snippet

Comment: A lot of things are undefined here.

Comment: what did you find undefined here? The problem is with just ctrl-z bindings, i think it might be just turned on somehow, i just can't find documentation on it.

Comment: The Notebook class, the defaultbg variable. Are these yours or from a library I'm missing?

Comment: it's ttk library and it's not related to a text widget itself

Comment: I imported ttk and I'm still getting errors with keyword arguments.

Comment: i didn't include any imports in the code, if you want to run it you need to import from ttk import Notebook, and also from Tkinter import *

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73449/discussion-between-malik-brahimi-and-bigoldtree).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, i found the information finally.

All i was needed is to set `undo` to `True` when i initialized text widget, just like this:

```
text = Text(frame,bd=3, width=145, height=30, yscrollcommand=bar.set, undo=True)
```

There is no need for `undo` function and `text.bind`. It works automatically when `undo` is `True`.

Comment: That's the correct solution, working perfectly well even with a `ScrolledText` widget! And for anyone else wondering, enabling undo also enables redo.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, you must set the `undo` keyword arg to `True` to activate the undo/redo stack. In Python 3 (at least 3.6), the stack is activated by default.

Comment: Actually, I needed to set undo=True in Python 3.10.7 on Ubuntu 22.04 to activate undo/redo.